# How can we pass multiple objects from an XMLSerializer function

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

How can we pass different objects of different classes by function overloading method?

Example code:

```
static public void SerializeToXML(Movie movie)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Movie));
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\movie.xml");
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, movie);
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

when i use this code:

```
static public void SerializeToXML(FbTextView p, FbTextField q)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer textviewserilizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FbTextView));
        XmlSerializer textfieldserilizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FbTextField));

        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\movie.xml");
        textviewserilizer.Serialize(textWriter, p);
        textfieldserilizer.Serialize(textWriter, q);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        while (ex != null)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            ex = ex.InnerException;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

its output xml display some result that is:

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element 
Location: file:///D:/movie.xml
Line Number 6, Column 14:</FbTextView><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                         -------------^
```

Comment: if i use attribute then parsing exception occur.

Comment: What do you mean with use attribute? I suspect that it is a separate issue.

Comment: @JohanLarsson: attribute mean to control serilization using attribute. e.g [XMLelement = "abc"]

Comment: @JohanLarsson : if we want to pass different objects like : movie , textview, textfield etc. these are objects of different classes. if we want to pass these objects from above serilization function. what kind of procedure we use ?

Comment: Regarding attributes all I can say is that it is possible, probably some minor error, do a search and start en new question if you dont find a solution. 
I don't understand the second question, your function returns void.

Comment: @JohanLarsson : can i paste code here ? so you can see it

Comment: You can try to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.80).aspx) first. If you still have problems after that perhaps it is better to start a new question?

Comment: @JohanLarsson: kindly check the updated code and error.

Comment: Bad idea to handle exceptions that way. Just output ex.ToString() and no loop.

Answer (score 6):

You can write it like this using [`generics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
public static void SerializeToXml<T>(this T objectToSerialize, string fileName)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
    using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, objectToSerialize);
    }
}
```

- Generics can be a little confusing at first but it is definitely worthwhile to learn. In short now your method accepts any type.
- Accepting every type might be too liberal and then you can [`constrain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) it to only accept certain types.
- It seems like a good idea to pass the file name as argument to your method, otherwise you can only use the method to write to one file(name).
- You can also read about the [`using statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- As L.B suggest you can turn your method into an [`extension method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) by adding the this keyword before the first argument.
- If you are going to implement it as extension method the method and the class must be static.

If you have your SerializeToXml method as an extension method you can call it in any of the two following ways, the result will be the same:

```
movie.SerializeToXml(@"C:\movie.xml");

SerializeToXml(movie, @"C:\movie.xml");
```

Answer (score 3):

An extension method can be used here

```
var xml = movie.SerializeToXML();

public static class SOExtensions
{
    public static string SerializeToXML<T>(this T obj)  where T : new()
    {
        StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.Serialize(s, obj);
        return s.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

For @[JohnSaunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders)' comment: *"-1 until you put that StringWriter in a using block"*

> "StringWriter Class" Implements a TextWriter for writing information to a string. The information is stored in an underlying **StringBuilder**.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx

and here are the codes of  StringWriter's and its base classes dispose.

```
//StringWriter
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    this._isOpen = false;
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}

//TextWriter
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
}
```

Comment: @JohnSaunders StringWriter doesn't use any resources to dispose. (GC can happily free arrays in Mem) I won't change it and wait you to cancel your downvote

Comment: @JohnSaunders I see you want me to accept your coding style without any reason. OK, I can start to inspect your answers :). At least this can make more fun than updating the titles.

Comment: Is there anything in the _contract_ of `StringWriter` that says that it will _never_ use any unmanaged resources? No? Is there anything in the contract of `StringWriter` that says that you should call `Dispose`? Yes. More important, you're setting a bad example for the readers.

Comment: @JohnSaunders `Is there anything in the contract of StringWriter that says that it will never use any unmanaged resources? No?` Yes, See the updated answer. I never encapsulated StringBuilder in *using* block

Comment: The code you posted is _today's_ code. Microsoft should be allowed to change it tomorrow.